# excel : using values from a cell to point at another cell

Tags: excel, cell

I'm certain it must be possible but I can't find the way to do this.

I have 2 columns, one with numbers and a second column with  dates.

for example:

number  date

1   21-Jul

2   22-Jul

3   23-Jul

4   24-Jul

5   25-Jul

6   26-Jul

7   27-Jul

8   28-Jul

9   29-Jul

10  30-Jul

At the top I have 2 cells 
one where I want to enter the relevant number and one where the connected date should be displayed.

Say the cell with 1 is cell B10 and the first date is C10
If I enter 1 in the cell above the other cell shoould display the date from C10
If I enter 7 in one cell the other should display the date from C16.

How do I use the number entered in one cell to point at another cell?
I tried things like

A1 - cell with the number

B1 - =C(9+A1)

but it isn't that simple.

It's frustrating how something that seems so simple is impossible for me to figure out.
I look forward to your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the function `VLOOKUP`.  Specifically, in cell B1 enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$b$10:$C$20,2,false)
```

Where

- A1 is the input cell,
- B10:C20 is the range containing your numbers/dates
- 2 tells EXCEl to lookup the value in the second column
- FALSE is a setting that forcesw Excel to find an exact match

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the index-match function combination.

=INDEX ( **Column I want a return value from** , ( MATCH ( **My Lookup Value** , **Column I want to Lookup against** ,  0 ))

Rather than give you a brief but possibly inadequate explanation, I'll give you a link to a thorough summary of how Index-match works:

http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I chose the other option but your answer looks equally promising.